# Doe SpriteKit not have a Mach-O universal binary on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: binary, sprite-kit, universal

I am writing a Lispworks application which provides an Objective C bridge. The Lispworks that I use is 32 bit.

I have been able to use SceneKit framework without any problems. However if I have to use SpriteKit, in Lisp I first initialize by loading the framework. When I do that, it fails wit this error:

> no suitable image found.  Did find:
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/SpriteKit.framework/SpriteKit: mach-o, but wrong architecture.

In order to resolve the issue, I checked the architectures supported by the frameworks on terminal. These are the outputs:

> $ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/SceneKit.framework
>
> $ file ./SceneKit
>
> > ./SceneKit: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
> >
> > ./SceneKit (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
> >
> > ./SceneKit (for architecture i386):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
>
> $ cd ../SpriteKit.framework
>
> $ file ./SpriteKit
>
> > ./SpriteKit: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

Is Sprite Kit 64 bit only? I could not find anything that says so.

Any suggestions to fix this much helpful. I do not want to proceed just by uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it, that should be the last option I guess.

***Env Info***

> 1. Lispworks 32 Bit
> 2. Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d)
> 3. OS X 10.10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Sprite Kit is 64-Bit only.

SK requires at least OS X version 10.9 (Mavericks) to be installed. OS X 10.9 is 64-Bit only. As an extension, Sprite Kit can only be used in 64-Bit apps/code.